# Почему middleware в ASP.NET Core требует определённую семантику, но не interface

Tags: c#, интерфейс, asp.net-core

Как известно, IApplicationBuilder в методе Configure стартапного класса в ASP.NET Core требует, чтобы класс middleware соответствовал определённой семантике (а именно, иметь метод Invoke, который получает HttpContext и возвращает Task), только не пойму, почему это не сделали в виде интерфейса? Ведь мне ничего не мешает написать что-то вроде:

```
public class FakeMiddleware
{

}
```

после чего это зарегистрировать:

```
        app.UseMiddleware<FakeMiddleware>();
```

и IApplicationBuilder это скушает как миленький (а как иначе, методу UseMiddleware не указано же, что стоит принимать) и получить ошибку уже в рантайме. Конечно, проблема не стоит и выеденного яйца и в случае ошибки будет заметна сразу, только почему сделали так некрасиво, если есть вполне изящное решение с интерфейсом?

Answer (score 1):

На англоязычном стековерфлов мне уже ответили, что это потому, что метод Invoke может иметь дополнительные параметры, которые автоматически будут разрешаться встроенным DI. Что логично. Только теперь возникает вопрос, что интерфейсы в том виде, в котором они есть, не покрывают полностью необходимую функциональность. Т.к. ситуация, когда могут быть дополнительные параметры, но которые по умолчанию могут быть разрешены и, следовательно, необязательны к передаче, далеко не ограничивается вышеописанным случаем с middleware.